# Regular Expression to replace part of a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace part of a string, it's dynamically generated so I'm never going to know what the string is.

Here's an example "session12_2" I need to replace the 2 at the end with a variable.  The "session" text will always be the same but the number will change.

I've tried a standard replace but that didn't work (I didn't think it would).

Here's what I tried:

```
col1 = col1.replace('_'+oldnumber+'"', '_'+rowparts[2]+'"');
```

Edit: I'm looking for a reg ex that will replace '_'+oldnumber when it's found as part of a string.

Comment: you need to get the dynamic number after 'session' ?

Comment: What's wrong with `.replace(/_\d+$/, whatYouNeed)`?

Comment: @raina77ow could you give me a bit more  info on how that would work please?

Comment: Avoid regex and use André's answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you will always have the "_" (underscore) as a divider you can do this:

```
 str = str.split("_")[0]+"_"+rowparts[x];
```

This way you split the string using the underscore and then complete it with what you like, no regex needed.

Comment: Just a little typo: You would actually be splitting the string, not the screen ;)

Comment: Or in translation: `col1 = col1.split('_')[0] +"_"+ rowparts[2];`

Comment: Thanks Markai. And Roko too. That is more like the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
var re = /session(\d+)_(\d+)/; 
var str = 'session12_2';
var subst = 'session$1_'+rowparts[2]; 

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

Test: https://regex101.com/r/sH8gK8/1

Comment: there's no need to use a **Capture group** before the `_`